# 'Only few' or 'only a few'

Tags: only

Which one of the following sentences would be correct (or both):

- Only a few friends came to his party yesterday.
- Only few friends came to his party yesterday.

Why I am asking this is because we had this sentence in a competition paper in my country and according to them, the second one is correct although it sounds wrong to me.

Edit: The first one was said to be incorrect.

Comment: Perhaps go to http://ell.stackexchange.com for help in learning English.

Comment: I disagree with the previous comment. I'd agree that 'only few ...' doesn't sound any more natural than 'really many ...', but I have found examples even in articles on grammar (and not as counterexamples). I can't find an article looking at the acceptability of pairing quantifiers with limiting modifiers. 'Only a few', 'rather a lot of' are acceptable, as are 'very few' and 'very many'. Perhaps there is an adjective ... quantifier gradience at work here.

Comment: `Few friends came` and `Only a few friends came` are common expressions, but not `Only few friends came`.

Comment: The phrase "*few friends*" (as opposed to "***a** few friends*") already implies "*only*".

Comment: I second @TrentBartlem 's comment. It would be acceptable to say "Few friends came", but not "Only few friends came". The latter sounds like something a non-native speaker may say, so you were correct in your suspicion that the second option sounds wrong, OP.

Answer (score -2):

"Only **a** few friends came to his party yesterday." is the correct sentence here based on my experience. I have to agree with you, the second one sounds incorrect.